# How can I set an output buffer name in php?

Tags: php, output-buffering, missing-features

I have been browsing the documentation for PHP's **[ob_get_status](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php)** function and found the following:

> Return Values:
>
> If called without the *full_status* parameter or with *full_status* =
> *FALSE* a simple array with the following elements is returned:
>
> ```
> Array (
>     [level] => 2
>     [type] => 0
>     [status] => 0
>     [name] => URL-Rewriter
>     [del] => 1 
> )
> ```

All seems pretty clear, however all of the internets seem to be unable to answer one question that arose - **how can I set the name of an output buffer?**

Is it even possible to do it? I coudln't find any clue in the documentation itself, or anywhere else.
However the documentation mentions that

> name = Name of active output handler or ' default output handler' if
> none is set

which pretty much *implies* it is possible to set it somehow.

Do you guys have any idea if this can be done? Any help would be greatly apprieciated.

Comment: You can't really set a name. `name` will be equal to the function name which handles the output buffering, e.g. `mb_output_handler`. http://php.net/mb_output_handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) you can turn on the output buffering in `PHP`.

Note that the function has such signature:

> bool ob_start ([ callable $output_callback = NULL [, int $chunk_size =
>   0 [, int $flags = PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS ]]] )

You can pass named function as a valid callback.

For example:

```
<?php

function test_handler($a) {
    return $a;
}

ob_start('test_handler');

var_dump(ob_get_status());
```

Will give you:

```
array(7) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "test_handler"
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["flags"]=>
  int(113)
  ["level"]=>
  int(0)
  ["chunk_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["buffer_size"]=>
  int(16384)
  ["buffer_used"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the name. It prints the name of the callback.

If your callback is a function called *foo_bar*:

```
[name] => "foo_bar"
```

If your callback is the method *foo_bar* of a class *Acme*:

```
[name] => "Acme::foo_bar"
```

If your callback is an anonymous function:

```
[name] => "Closure::__invoke"
```

Answer (score 1):

The name that you set on the output buffer is the name of the output handler that is called when it is flushed.

Eg

```
ob_start('my_buffer');


function my_buffer($buff){
    return str_replace(":)","<img src=\"smiley\"/>",$buff);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I wonder why there is no mention of this in the documentation whatsoever.